# Doctrine schema tool create command fails - ReflectionException Class does not exist

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

We're using Doctrine YAML files to generate our entities. When I run `../../vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities src` from the folder where my `bootstrap.php` and `cli-config.php` is it appears to generate the PHP entity classes correctly:

```
../../vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities src
Generating Doctrine entities...
Processing entity "Entity\BucketGroup"
Processing entity "Entity\Cheat"
Processing entity "Entity\Content"
Processing entity "Entity\ContentGroup"
Processing entity "Entity\ContentType"
Processing entity "Entity\Developer"
Processing entity "Entity\ExternalIdentityProvider"
Processing entity "Entity\Game"
Processing entity "Entity\GameRelease"
Processing entity "Entity\Genre"
Processing entity "Entity\HighlightedContent"
Processing entity "Entity\Media"
Processing entity "Entity\MediaGroup"
Processing entity "Entity\Platform"
Processing entity "Entity\ProsAndCons"
Processing entity "Entity\Publisher"
Processing entity "Entity\Rating"
Processing entity "Entity\Region"
Processing entity "Entity\Site"
Processing entity "Entity\Tag"
Processing entity "Entity\User"
Processing entity "Entity\UserExternalIdentityProvider"
Processing entity "Entity\VideoAdvert"
```

Next when I run `../../vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` I get the following PHP error stack trace:

```
PHP Warning:  class_parents(): Class Entity\BucketGroup does not exist and could not be loaded in /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php:43
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:41
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:899
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
PHP   9. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:47
PHP  10. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:112
PHP  11. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:205
PHP  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:281
PHP  13. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:257
PHP  14. class_parents() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:40
PHP Warning:  array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 257
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php:43
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:41
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:899
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
PHP   9. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:47
PHP  10. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:112
PHP  11. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:205
PHP  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:281
PHP  13. array_reverse() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:257
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 257
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php:43
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:41
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:899
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
PHP   9. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:47
PHP  10. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:112
PHP  11. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:205
PHP  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /vagrant/www/creo.api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:281



[ReflectionException]
Class Entity\BucketGroup does not exist
```

The BucketGroup PHP entity file is definitely be created correctly and is correctly namespaced.

For reference is my `bootstrap.php` file:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

include '../../vendor/autoload.php';

$isDevMode = true;

$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__ . '/config/yaml'], $isDevMode);

// The included file is generated by db-generate-schema Chef recipe and include the DB connection parameters in an array called $conn
include ('dbgenerate.php');

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

and here is my `cli-config.php` file:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

$entityManager->getConnection()
              ->getDatabasePlatform()
              ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($entityManager->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($entityManager)
]);
```

I'm using the latest version of Doctrine loaded via Composer (2.3.4).

Can anyone point me in the direction as to what is going wrong please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with your composer setup.  Add this to the psr-0 section (in the autoload section) in your composer.json:

```
"Entity\\": "src/"
```